# Efficiently map over 18 BILLION input values to a few output values

Tags: c#, .net, collections

It seems that the information given below (the line) was not clear enough, so I am attempting to be more clear and concise.

I need suggestions as to how I might map billions of ulong values to a few int values. In the worst case I have over 11 billion (basically random ulong values) that need to map to 40 int values.  The mapping is known and a dictionary would work except for the amount of memory needed.  Currently, it's estimated that approximately 199GB of RAM would be used for all needed mappings when using a dictionary.

Does anyone know of any kind of algorithm or process that can be used to accomplish this mapping without consuming so much RAM?

---

I am working on a C# - .NET 4.5 program to help filter my data and have run into an efficiency problem.  I am currently running my data through 8 (I ultimately need to do 20) different filters with each one filtering the data the same way but at different levels.   At a certain point in the filter process each level has many values that must be encoded into the final output value.

Some examples:

At level 3 there are 23 values to be encoded into 6 possible output values (0-5).

At level 7 there are 2,576 values to be encoded into 14 possible output values (0-13).

At level 10 there are 88,215 values to be encoded in into 20 possible output values (0-19).

By the time I get to level 20 I will have over 11 BILLION values to be encoded into 40 output values (0-39).

The values to be encoded for each filter are all known in advance and I am reading this information from files and filling a separate dictionary for each filter (currently 1 to 8).  At this rate by the time I get to filter 20 there will be over 16.5 BILLION total dictionary entries with most of them being ulong values.

This is not a solution in the long run.

Does anyone know of a way to map millions of unique input values into a few unique output values more efficiently?

Is there an algorithm that will map the inputs to the outputs?

I am looking for any ideas that may point me in the right direction.

Comment: I fear this is too vague for anyone to be able to help. Without knowing what your filters do or why (or if) they are needed, it is mostly impossible to offer advice on how to improve efficiency

Comment: I have a problem. Can you tell me the solution to my problem?

Comment: I think based on the info you've given, the dictionary approach sounds perfectly reasonable. It is a data structure specifically designed to map large numbers of unique inputs to outputs. Are you encountering any specific problem with your current approach?

Comment: A tip for large dictionaries is to pre set the size to something large, this will prevent needing to expand the internal structures.

Comment: Memory mapped files might alleviate the memory footprint. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx to get started.

Comment: @KeithPayne - OP does not yet have any problem (since there is no solid measured data nor goals in the post), so offering something not exactly simple/obvious to use like Memory mapped files does not feel like a good approach. It likely cause more pain than solve anything as you can't map whole files in common case so you have to write a lot of code around it... On other hand it can be used as replacement for [regular expressions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) as programming hammer :).

Comment: Why 16 million is too much for you? Did you measure it? (Obviously your question so far is off-topic as "propose algorithm I would like for unknown problem with unspecified restrictions"  is way subjective)

Comment: My bad. It's over 16 billion not million mappings. If the inputs to the dictionaries are ulong (8 bytes) and the outputs are int (4 bytes) then there is a need for just under 200 GB of memory to hold the data.  Way more than most PCs have.

Comment: I have been looking into AI, ANN and SOMs. All inputs and outputs are known in advance.  Could a SOM be trained until it would give correct answers 100% of the time? Anyone with AI experience have any input if this is worth pursuing?

Comment: Are there rules which determine which value is mapped to what? I think we need info on what you are trying to achieve. It might be an XY problem where a new approach might obviate the need for such a memory intensive solution.

Comment: What is the range of values to which those 16E9 numbers will belong? Is it (0, 16E9) or is it larger?

Comment: Baldrick - Dialecticus Thanks for responding. My worst case is needing to map 11,000,000,000 ish values out of 538,000,000,000  ish (2^39) possible.  Because of the way this process works there will only ever be the 11B and they are very much random as to how they map to the final values of 0-39.

Comment: Here is a small sample from filter 5 which maps 244 input values to 10 possible output values (0 to 9).  1st # = input, 2nd # = output.
0 , 5
1 , 6
2 , 6
7 , 7
4 , 6
5 , 7
14 , 7
31 , 8
8 , 6
9 , 7
10 , 7
28 , 7
29 , 8
62 , 8
127 , 9
16 , 4
.
.
.
328 , 6
329 , 6
330 , 6
348 , 2
349 , 0
336 , 4
337 , 4
338 , 4
343 , 0
340 , 2
341 , 0
384 , 5
385 , 6
386 , 6
391 , 7
388 , 6
389 , 7
398 , 7
415 , 7
392 , 6
393 , 7
394 , 7
412 , 7
413 , 7
446 , 1
400 , 4
401 , 7
402 , 7
407 , 7
404 , 7
405 , 7
440 , 3
441 , 3
442 , 1
416 , 5
417 , 5
418 , 5
423 , 5
420 , 5
421 , 5
430 , 1
424 , 3
425 , 3
426 , 1

Comment: I would use a big file that is in essence a big array of buckets. Position of the bucket uses first X bits of the number. Size of the bucket is fixed, and should be large enough that all numbers that begin with given X bits can be stored there. Content of the bucket is array of pairs (number without first X bits, mapped value), sorted by first item in the pair. Header of a bucket should contain the number of items in the bucket. If that number is larger than the bucket can contain then that is the sign that remaining items are in the next bucket (with items that actually belong to next bucket)

Comment: Bucket header must have a number of items that actually belong to some previous bucket (so it must have two numbers). This number is needed so that you can skip those items in the bucket that do not concern you. Also, it would be nice if bucket header occupies the same space as one bucket item.

Comment: Also, instead of having bucket headers those data in headers can stand in the beginning of the file, and also in memory during program run. That would simplify the code. This algorithm relies on numbers being evenly distributed. If they are not then the code will run slowly.

Comment: Dialecticus - Thanks for taking the time to help me with this. I think I understand what you are suggesting but the randomness of the input values prevents this from adding much reduction.  After looking at filter 6 I  would get only about a 4 % total reduction.  There are very few places where 2 or more input values are back to back (could go into the same bucket) and point to the same desired output.

Comment: What is the nature of the data? Are those data static and neverchanging? Or are they created once for the life time of the application, and never changed and discarded when the application closes? Or are they changed occasionally? What is the frequency of creating data, changing data, and reading data?

Comment: The data is fixed.  It currently resides in separate CSV files, one for each filter.  Filters 1 to 9 are currently being used.  The CSV files are read when the program loads and populate the dictionaries currently being used.  It’s basically just a large lookup table and I was hoping that there was a way to do this in some kind of algorithm.  I am currently investigating if there is some way to process the inputs and generate the Boolean equations for each output.  So far anything I have found to process the data to do this, stops after a couple of thousand input lines.

Comment: Are values sorted in CSV file? BTW, how big is this CSV file?

Comment: The CSV values are not currently sorted, but they could easily be. Filter 9 is the largest filter so far that's working with over 27K entries. The pre processing for filter 10 is still running and should be complete later next week.  When complete it will have over 88K entries. The file size for filter 9 is 317K. But this is only one of many with each one much greater than the previous one.  Thanks again for your assistance!

Comment: Filter 10 completes next week? Wow. I'm curious, when will filter 20 complete? How big will be the CSV file for filter 20? So, it would be very nice if values in CSV file were sorted. And I don't mean output values (0-39), but input values (2^39). In that case we can forget about the buckets.

Comment: Although we know exactly how many and the value of the inputs for this step for each filter, we do not know the corresponding output value.  The pre processing of filter 10 to find these output values was originally estimated to take just under 9000 years at 4000 tests a second.  With research and optimizations it will now complete in under 12 days. We are working on breaking up the other filters to use multi-machines as well as multi cores. Filter 20 will produce CSV files with a total of more than 11 billion entries. Don't know the file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values in input CSV file are sorted, and the data never changes, we can abandon the bucket approach from the comments and just cram all the data pairs in one big array in file. The goal is to have data better organized, to enable fast reading, and so avoid having whole dataset in memory. You would have to convert the CSV file to a new binary format, and in the process create the index array in memory. This index array should also be saved to some index file, so that it can be used when the program is restarted. In memory you would only hold the array of positions of the first data pair whose value begins with item's index. In file you would have just a huge array of 32-bit (4 byte) numbers, where first 3 bytes of each number is leftover of the indexed item in memory and last byte is our output.

To create index array you would read CSV file line by line. For each datapair (`input_int`, `output_int`) create new datapair (`index`, `32-bit value`). `Index` takes first 2 bytes of `input_int`, and `32-bit value` is created concatenating last 3 bytes of `input_int` and a sole byte of `output_int`. If `index` is changed from the previous datapair then store file's position to array at new index. In any case append `32-bit value` to file. Repeat until the end of CSV file.

So let's say we have an input value 0x1234567890 and need corresponding output value. Algorithm would find the items in the array in memory with indexes 0x1234 and 0x1235. This would give you the start and end position in the file where our item might be. In this range we do a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) for the value 0x567890 and take the byte that follows it. That's our output value.

Comment: That’s a novel approach and should work good using a solid state drive.  I will look into this as well as the ANN solution I am perusing.
Thanks you very much for your answer.  It really does help to have a fresh vantage point.

Comment: Just a follow up.  It turns out that an over trained neural network works very well.  At least so far. Filter 9 has over 27K input patterns and the net is giving 100% accurate output results.